# Using ObjectBindingDatasource to bind to object exposing Lists, cant drag and drop fields onto report designer

Tags: c#

Ive used the ObjectBindingDatasource to bind to a class Ive called "ReportViewModel" which contains properties such as

List Companies {get; set;}
List Managers {get; set;}

in its constructor Im just calling a method to populate with dummy data

Managers = new ReportDataRepository().GetManagers();
Companies = new ReportDataReposiroty().GetCompanies();
...

When i create the new Datasource , it shows the ReportViewModel class with the Lists under it. I expand the Companies object and attempt draging and dropping fields onto the report designer and it works. Though doesnt allow me to drag and drop for any other List.

Any guidance would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After establishing a new datasource Ive been told I have to close and reopen VS since the report designer isnt refreshing, this then allows me to drag and drop as usual.